# How to use sub addressing (plus sign) in mu4e and mu?

Tags: mu4e, email

Many email providers, incl. gmail, support sub addressing using a plus sign.
E.g. an email address `rosie@emailprovider.com` can have an unlimited number of sub addresses like `rosie+sammy@emailprovider.com` etc.
So far, I have accumulated hundreds of such sub addresses.
How can I tell `mu` that everything matching `rosie+*@emailprovider.com` is actually my email address?
How can use my addresses efficiently, esp. in replies?
Having one context per email sub address is not an option, of course.
Thanks for any help!